# Impersonated Service Account ADC vs Service Account Key Security

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I am in the process of migrating from service account keys to attaching service accounts to my cloud run instances. I have managed to impersonate service accounts for local development and store credential configuration files in a separate json for each application (I have a separate service account for each app, as recommended). I then set the ADC by setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var and this is working well.

My question is, what happens if these ADC config files were to be exposed? Does it cause the same issues as an exposed service account key?

Comment: Why do you need a ADC config file on Cloud Run? If you talk about YOUR ADC credential file, in which there is the access token, refresh token and the impersonated SA, yes, it's the same issue because with the refresh token you can get a new access token and do whatever YOUR account can on Google Cloud

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the ADC config file only when developing locally. When deploying to cloud run I simply attach the service account. Okay that's good to know. The advantage with the credential files is that they only need to be stored locally and kept secure so.

Comment: Yes, and you touch a point I discussed many time with Google. You can create several configuration with gcloud. But this configuration does not take into account your own credential `gcloud auth login`. Therefore, when you have several impersonation to do `gcloud auth login --impersonate-service-account=....` you have to save the ADC file for each "configuration" you have. And it's super boring!